# Swift subclass adoption of a custom protocol by binding to superclass

Tags: swift, generics, core-data

Suppose that you have NSManagedObject class hierarchy.

```
class Dog: NSManagedObject {
    var name: String?
}

class Person: NSManagedObject {
   var name: String?
}
```

Of course, you would like not to duplicate code.

You declare protocol.

```
protocol Has_Name_Protocol {
    var name: String? {get}
}
extension Has_Name_Protocol {
    static func predicate(name: String?) -> NSPredicate {
        return predicate(names: [name])
    }

    static func predicate(names: [String?]?) -> NSPredicate {
        return NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", argumentArray: names?.flatMap({$0}))
    }
}
```

Of course, it is not enough, you would like to introduce find method that search for an object.

For that reason you should bind protocol to the lowest bound in class hierarchy that fit.

```
extension Has_Name_Protocol where Self: NSManagedObject {
    static func find(name: String?, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And also add extension for a subclass that fit this protocol.

```
extension Dog: Has_Name_Protocol {}
extension Person: Has_Name_Protocol {}
```

Is it a right way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `associatedtype` and use this as type. You need also to add `entityType` for convenience.

Consider to declare `name` as non-optional. This avoids all unwrapping and flat mapping. And make the `find` method `throws` and pass-through the Core Data error

Untested code

```
protocol HasNameProtocol {
    associatedtype FetchableType: NSManagedObject = Self
    static var entityName : String { get }
    var name: String {get}

    static func predicate(name: String) -> NSPredicate
    static func find(name: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [FetchableType]

}

extension HasNameProtocol where FetchableType == Self {    

    static var entityName : String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    }

   static func predicate(name: String) -> NSPredicate {
        return NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)
    }

    static func find(name: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [FetchableType] {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<FetchableType>(entityName: entityName)
        let predicate = predicate(name: name)
        request.predicate = predicate
        return try context.fetch(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, but it seems too complex. However, it doesn't work without specifying adoption of protocol in subclass extension.

Comment: Of course you have to adopt the protocol in the `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

> Of course, you would like not to duplicate code.

This is not a reason to use protocols. [Protocols are more than a bag of syntax.](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/) You first need to ask "do these usages of `name` have a semantic equivalence such that sharing implementations has a valuable meaning?" You should not ask "do these classes include the same set of keystrokes?" That can be by coincidence, and is not a good reason to merge them since they may evolve in different ways if they are semantically different.

```
extension Has_Name_Protocol {
    static func predicate(name: String?) -> NSPredicate {
        return predicate(names: [name])
    }

    static func predicate(names: [String?]?) -> NSPredicate {
        return NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", argumentArray: names?.flatMap({$0}))
    }
}
```

This lacks the kind of coherence that you'd want in a protocol's extension. Why is it natural to pass `String?` when `name` is of type `String`? What value is this creating over:

```
func predicate(property: String, values: [String]) -> NSPredicate {
    return NSPredicate(format: "\(property) == %@", argumentArray: values)
}

func namePredicate(names: [String]) -> NSPredicate {
    return predicate(property: "name", values: names)
}
```

This seems instead just to be shuffling syntax rather than creating a valuable layer of abstraction.

```
static func find(name: String?, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self?
```

This signature is confusing. Why is `name` optional? What does it mean to "find something with no name" when you've said that everything this applies to must have a name (that being the entire point of the protocol)?

The basic concept here is fine as a syntactic convenience if you found you had many implementations of `find` that were identical in both syntax and semantics, but I would strongly ask whether these things have a deeper similarity than "they have a name." If that is their only important similarity, then the protocols should be called `Named` not `Has_Name_Protocol`.

Comment: It is a generic question with concrete data example. 
"Signature is confusing", no, it is not confusing in case of Core Data generated fields.

Next, "Named" is a bad name for protocol like other plain names. Why so? Because protocols are scoped to module level.

Comment: Understood that you mean it to be generic, but as you create a concrete example, I believe it will have the same problems. Trying to over-generic Swift is the #1 cause I've found of developer confusion. Wait until you have 3 implementations, then build your generic. Core Data doesn't change the issue; if the field is not optional, don't mark it optional in the model and don't let Core Data create an optional property. This dramatically simplifies code throughout the project. `Has_Name_Protocol` is precisely as generic as `Named`. The genericness suggests the problem (it doesn't mean enough).